# Why is number of entities displayed in Layers panel for particular layer different from actual number of entities in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

Why is the number of entities displayed in the Layers panel for a particular layer different from the actual number of entities?

The database used is "SpatiaLite" type.

Has anyone noticed this kind of problem so far?

[image]

The problem disappears if the data is saved as "shape" format.[image]

Comment: I'm pretty sure one is a quick estimate, so counting doesn't slow QGIS down too much for big datasets.

Comment: Do you have any invalid geometries?

Comment: There are no invalid geometries. Verification Method: Vector / Geometry Tools / Validation Verification.